# How to split data inside list into individual separate columns using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split data inside Names into individual separate columns using pandas

```py
import pandas as pd

name_dict = {
            'Name': ['a|b|c|d|e']
          }

df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)

print (df)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have 6 columns, 'Name' and the letters a-e or just have a-e?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `str.split()` to split value by `|`, as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

name_dict = {
    'Name': ['a|b|c|d|e']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(name_dict)
print(df)
#        Name
#0  a|b|c|d|e

df = df['Name'].str.split('|', expand=True)
print(df)
#   0  1  2  3  4
#0  a  b  c  d  e

# to change column names
df = df.rename(
    columns={
        0: 'a',
        1: 'b',
        2: 'c',
        3: 'd',
        4: 'e',
    }
)
print(df)
#   a  b  c  d  e
#0  a  b  c  d  e
```

For more information, such as advanced options, please refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html

Comment: @AK007 Sure, I've updated the code renaming the column names